# dnf/yum seems broken (segmentation fault (core dumped) )

Tags: curl, segmentation-fault, yum, dnf

I encounter the following problem each time I try to use yum or dnf:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I have no idea on how to resolve this! I am running on a fedora 24 distribution (virtual machine)

`libcurl` version seems to be 7.47.1.  (I strongly suspect my lib curl to be broken and creating the segmentation fault)

[image: broken yum/dnf command]

[image: curl segmentation fault]

Is there a way to repair this?

Comment: is my question not clear, misses some information ?